# Transpose row in column with unknown number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to transpose rows to columns in SQL Server.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Test]
(
    [PolNumber] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [PolType] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [submitted] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [DocName] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here is some sample data:

```
insert into Tbl_Test(PolNumber, PolType, submitted, DocName)
values
('St4','Tuesday', '15:00','Coach4'), ('St1','Friday', '15:00','Coach1'),
('St4', 'Thursday', '10:30', 'Coach3'), ('St1','Friday', '15:30', 'Coach1');
```

Here is my query I tried to used

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                       ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[DocName])
                   FROM Tbl_Test c 
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

                 
SET @query = 'SELECT [PolNumber], PolType , '+@cols+'from (SELECT [PolNumber],[PolType],[submitted] AS [amount],[DocName] AS [category] FROM Tbl_Test)x pivot (max(amount) for category in ('+@cols+')) p';

EXECUTE (@query);
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

The problem is that the 'St1' for Friday is listed one time with coach1 instead of two times: for 15:00 and 15:30

The result I am seeking is like this

[image]

Comment: Ideally, if you can, do this type of thing in the presentation layer, not the RDBMS. But, for what you have, the easiest way to debug your dynamic SQL is the `PRINT`/`SELECT` the dynamic statement, debug that, and then propagate the solution to the dynamic statement.

Comment: @lptr thank you, I need to digest/understand how dense_rank() over works

Comment: @lptr , I tried another sample, and it is not working like it should example (st2, for Wednesday, is on two lines instead of once) :  insert into Tbl_Test(PolNumber, PolType, submitted, DocName)
values
('St4','Tuesday', '15:00','Coach4'), ('St1','Friday', '15:00','Coach1'),
('St4', 'Thursday', '10:30', 'Coach3'), 
('St2','Tuesday', '15:00','Coach4'),
('St2','Wednesday', '15:00','Coach2'),
('St2','Wednesday', '16:00','Coach1'),
('St2','Tuesday', '15:30','Coach4'),
('St1','Friday', '15:30', 'Coach1');

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.